# Pymongo's update_one() returns UpdateResult with AttributeError

Tags: python, mongodb, pycharm, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I just upgraded my MongoDB and Pymongo to the latest version 3.2.1 to be able to use the [*UpdateResult*](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/results.html?_ga=1.66820142.1654018748.1454241415#pymongo.results.UpdateResult) object after calling *update_one()*.
But for some reason the returned object has one field that contains an **AttributeError**.

Take a look at my [Pycharm screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0DgX.png). You can see that *_UpdateResult__acknowledged*

```
'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/pycharm-community-5.0.4/helpers/pydev/pydevd_resolver.py", line 191, in _getPyDictionary
    attr = getattr(var, n)
AttributeError: _UpdateResult__acknowledged'
```

It causes me a problem since I am trying to catch all exceptions and every time I need to use update_one() in my code I get this exception.

This is a snippet of my code:

```
QUERY = {id: '1234'}
try:
    record = mongoCollection.find_one(QUERY)
    if record is None:
        print 'Add new Record'
    else:
        updateResult = mongoCollection.update_one(
            QUERY,
            {'$addToSet': {'info': getInfo()}}
        )

        if updateResult['modified_count'] == 1:
            mongoCollection.update_one(
                QUERY,
                {'$inc': {'infoCount': 1}}
            )
        print 'Record exists, updating if needed'
except:
    print 'Failed to add/update'
```

Luckily I was able to find a workaround that doesn't cause this exception to be raised.
Instead of using *update_one()*, I can use the deprecated function *update()* which returns only the RAW result from MongoDB and then instead of comparing *updateResult['modified_count']*, I can just compare updateResult['nModified'].

But this is definitely not a best practice to use deprecated functions... :(

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 18):

For those who may encounter the same error, I was able to get an answer here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-1055

In short, since UpdateResult is not a python dictionary and doesn't implement `__getitem__`. The problem was trying to do

```
 updateResult['modified_count'] == 1
```

instead I should have used

```
 updateResult.modified_count == 1
```

because `UpdateResult.modified_count` is a property.

Comment: You should mark this as answered. You provide a good solution to the problem.